# export gridview to Excel : making changes to gv before it its rendered to control

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

Im using the following code in order to export a gridview to excel

```
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";


Response.Charset = "";
EnableViewState = false;
Controls.Add(frm);

frm.Controls.Add(this.myGridView);
frm.RenderControl(hw);
```

[Source for above exporting code](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/443553/Export-Gridview-to-excel)

Everything works like a charm.
Except I now have to make changes to the gridview before it gets exported to Excel.
E.g. One change is that I needed to remove a column.
Yet I cant do this:

```
  //I can't remove columns here, since it has not been rendered yet and has 0 columns
  frm.Controls.Add(this.myGridView);
  frm.RenderControl(hw);
```

Is there a way to edit the Gridview before it is exported? e.g .Remove a column

Comment: Before the first line of your code, make the column `visible="False"`

Comment: negative, cant access anything on the gridview since it has not been rendered yet - column count is 0 if i look at it